# Performance issue when assigning the same function to multiple variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, function, prototype

> [Edited] Important! Function is treated as object, not value. So this question is invalid because it is based on a wrong assumption. This edit serves as a note to avoid confusing anyone who read this question.

Let's say I have a function expression of foo

```
var foo = function() {
    return this.member;
}
```

and I have the following class and instantiate many objects of it with "foo" as the callback function.

```
var simpleClass = function(callback) {
    this.member = "I am an instance variable";
    this.callback = callback;
}
var a = new simpleClass(foo);
var b = new simpleClass(foo);
var c = new simpleClass(foo);
.
.
.
```

Since in JavaScript arguments are passed by value, we are copying the <strike>value</strike>([Edited]actually it should be object) of foo to a, b, c and other variables' callback. If my understanding is correct, then foo will be copied n times, each occupying certain memory space for each object.

Base on this understanding, I have some performance questions regarding this situation:

> 1. Does copying functions to multiple variables harm the performance?

Since each copies of "foo" as simpleClass object's "callback" occupies space, if there are really many simpleClass object(e.g. in a DOM library I have thousands of DOM objects which has the same function css()), will it harm the performance significantly? Or most JavaScript engine has mechanism to tackle this situation and it generally won't harm at all?

> 2. In situation where potentially hundreds or thousands of object will be created. Is it always a good practice to put those shared functions to the prototype of an object?

Since all the object instance share the same class prototype, if we put the "foo" function to the prototype of simpleClass, then there should have only one copy of the "foo" and every object instance will just execute the prototype copy of "foo" when needed. Is this a good practice we should follow?

I try to search for similar keywords but couldn't find the right wordings to find the solution to this problem. Please correct my wordings if I make anything unclear. And of course if I have any misunderstandings please correct me too. I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Functions are objects and are not copied on assignment. You've created 3 `.callback` properties, but there's only one function.

Comment: I didn't know functions are objects as well. I always thought it is more like a "value". Thank you and I have updated my question to avoid confusing the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand this well enough to give you an authoritative answer but I can say this:

> then foo will be copied n times, each occupying certain memory space for each object.

This is incorrect. `foo` is a variable pointing to a function. `foo` is not the function, if you did `var bar = foo`, `bar` now also points to the function, the *same* function. So the function is not copied. A reference to the function is assigned to `this.callback`.

> 2. In situation where potentially hundreds or thousands of object will be created. Is it always a good practice to put those shared functions to the prototype of an object?

What is and isn't good practise in JavaScript is up for debate. Some people like to use class/prototype, other people use object literals. It's definitly true though that `prototype` can help reduce the memory footprint of your application. See it like this: if you're using `prototype` you're giving the JavaScript engine more information about the object, ie. that your object is similar to all these other objects. The JavaScript engine should be able to make optimizations based on that. I can't say too much about the exact numbers, it might vary wildly per vendor.

---

Your code sample is equivalent to this:

```
function foo() {}
function myClass() {
    this.foo = foo;
}
var instance = new myClass();
```

If you used prototypes you'd write:

```
function myClass() {}
myClass.prototype.foo = function () {};
var instance = new myClass();
```

If you used object literals you'd have:

```
function foo() {};
function create_myClass() {
    return {
        foo: foo
    };
}
var instance = create_myClass();
```

In all the cases above the function `foo` is never *copied*. In these cases below you *do* create a new copy of `foo` every time:

```
function myClass() {
    this.foo = function () {}; // new copy every time
}
var instance = new myClass();

function create_myClass() {
    return {
        foo: function () {}; // new copy every time
    };
}
```

---

As for performance. This is the tip I always give: don't start optimizing until you run into a measurable problem. Always measure with real data. Additionally, if you think your way of doing things is good then it's likely that JavaScript engine vendors will optimize for that method.

Comment: You do understand it well enough to give a correct and helpful answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript reference is copied not the object itself so you can't assign the value to callback to change the function from inside constructor. You your code all those object will share the function, look at this snipet:

```js
var foo = function() {
    return this.member;
}

var simpleClass = function(callback) {
    this.member = "I am an instance variable";
    this.callback = callback;
}
var a = new simpleClass(foo);
var b = new simpleClass(foo);
alert(a.callback === b.callback ? 'shared' : 'not shared');
```

Comment: Worth noting that a decent JS engine would use the same function internally in memory even if logically in JS it has been "copied".

Comment: @JamesThorpe the function is not copied. It's like doing `var bar = foo; console.log(bar === foo)`.

Comment: @Halcyon I know, I'm talking about in situations where it is - eg creating one inside a loop.

Comment: @JamesThorpe so you mean: `function foo(){};function bar(){}`, internally the engine would optimize `foo` and `bar` as being the same function, but `foo === bar` would still resolve false?

Comment: I think that's the sort of thing that goes on these days, yes

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Creating functions in a loop will still create multiple function objects, which *does* have an overhead. Sure, function objects are rather small, and their (non-observable) code will be shared, but it's not the same optimisation as referring multiple times to the exact same function.